# Using StatusHandler in E4

Tags: eclipse-plugin, e4

In E3, each class could handle a status like this:

```
IStatus status = new Status(IStatus.WARNING, TestPlugin.PLUGIN_ID, "Hello World");
StatusManager.getManager().handle(status, StatusManager.SHOW);
```

Now it seems a bit more tricky. [This documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/EAS/Status_Reporting) guesses this should work for classes that support injection:

```
@Inject Provider<StatusHandler> statusHandler;
@Inject Provider<StatusReportingService> statusReportingService;

public void foo() {
  try {
    // some operation
  } catch (SomeException ex) {
     statusHandler.get().handle(ex, IStatus.ERROR, "Error Message", statusReportingService.get());
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't. Since there were no imports in the example (and why would there? There are only 4 `Provider` classes in plain java), I guessed they meant `javax.inject.Provider` and tried to inject `org.eclipse.jface.util.StatusHandler`:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to instantiate public org.eclipse.jface.util.StatusHandler()
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.ConstructorRequestor.execute(ConstructorRequestor.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.makeFromProvider(InjectorImpl.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.ProviderImpl.get(ProviderImpl.java:34)
    at org.acme.project.Main.createStatusHandler(StatusUtil.java:26)
```

So maybe that's not the right `StatusHandler`? How do I use the `StatusHandler` in E4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this was never implemented. Instead the `org.eclipse.e4.core.services.statusreporter.StatusReporter` class can be injected and used to log or show errors.

```java
@Inject
StatusReporter statusReporter;

statusReporter.report(status, StatusReporter.SHOW | StatusReporter.LOG);
```

Comment: I have encountered a similar issue. Nevertheless, when following your advice, I get a compiler warning: "Discouraged access: The type 'StatusReporter' is not API". Should I be concerned about this and is there any other alternative?

Comment: @Pyves Normally that is a problem, but for e4 APIs it is OK. A lot of e4 APIs have still not been completely finalized so give this warning.